# control volume and play .mp3 on click (div)

Tags: jquery, audio, volume

I keep getting new idea's thus new problems and questions so Im asking for help again!

Problem/what I would like solved : I have 4 .mp3 files, 
-I want to be able to click on a div/ahref and start the sound. 
-I want to be able to play MULTIPLE files at once
-I'd love a volume slider for all the sounds or for each sound separately

I already came a long way thanks to SO, here is what I have at the moment: http://eduweb.hhs.nl/~14042568/Help/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //ready document, execute function
$(".parent").click(function(){ //add event to class
    var color = $(this).data("color") //add variable get color-data
    $("#home").css("background-color", color); //change property
    var audio = new Audio('./mp3/piano.mp3'); //only plays piano<-- PROBLEM
    audio.play(); //play sound
});
});
```

the purple(right top) is already working, the problem is the jQuery is fixed on playing one sound only, this is a problem as I said.

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into html5's `<audio>` tag? It does a lot of the things that you are looking for. Here is the link for more info.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

**EDIT**

Here is all you need to do with the html audio tag:

```
<audio src="directoryToFile/subDir/yourSong.mp3" controls></audio>
```

The attribute `controls` gives you the play button, the volume, mute, time, and the select which part of the song to play slider.

To be honest not every browser will play mp3's so the way to get around that is to put multiple sources to the same song but in different formats. Like so:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="dir/yourSong.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <source src="dir/yourSong.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="dir/yourSong.3gp" type="audio/3gp">
    <p>Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element </p>
</audio>
```

This allows the which ever browser the user is using to decide what is best for it.

There is the `loop` attribute which allows the song to repeat when done.

Then there is the `preload=""` attribute. This is used for large files you can set it equal to none, auto or metadata

Finally, if you want your site to be really annoying you can give the element the `autoplay` attribute (please, I beg you to don't use the autoplay).

The best part is no JavaScript or JQuery needed. Sure you can do more fancy things with the audio tag using JS with JQuery but it isn't required.

Comment: Yes I have, I don't know how I would go about having the sound play when I press on a div, whilst keeping the audio functions how I want them...this is hard for a noob in jQuery :( All i saw in your link was javascript, which i am even worse at. That is why im trying to do with it jquery haha :p

Comment: The audio tag should be able to minimize your use of jQuery and JS for this part. If you are looking into getting more into JS coding give this a read. 

http://www.maritimejournal.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/1033940/Javascript-The-Good-Parts.pdf

Just so you know JQuery is a library for JavaScript so every time you use JQuery you are using technically using JS which in turn makes you a JS coder. :)